# Show coordinates as label at render

Tags: text-object, coordinates

Is there a way to add labels on a rendered image with properties such as the coordinates fo an object?

i.e. when the object moves in the video you can see the coordinates change

Comment: With the addon "animation nodes" it should be easy to do. I'm not familiar enough with this to make a proper answer though. There are plenty of tutorials, basically, you will need to create text objects and animate their displayed text by copying other objects' transforms.